# Python converting temperature error

Tags: python, syntax-error

I tried writing this code to convert temp from Fahrenheit to Celsius and Vice-versa.

```
try:
        temperature=raw_input ("Enter temperature in numerals only")
        temp1=float(temperature)
        conversion=raw_input ("Convert to (F)ahrenheit or (C)elsius?")
def celtofah():
        temp2 = (9/5)*temp1+32
        print temp1," C = ",temp2," F"
def fahtocel():
        temp2 = (5/9)*(temp1-32)
        print temp1," F = ",temp2," C"
if conversion == F:
        celtofah()
elif conversion == C:
        fahtocel()

except:
        print "Please enter a numeric value"
```

However I seem to be getting an error on line 5 where I have defined the celtofah function.

[image]

I don't think the indentation is wrong here although I could be missing out on something.

Comment: *I dont think the indentation is wrong* - please **make sure** it isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is your indentation, even without looking at your image.
To make it work you can simply indent all the def and if/elif's.
But even better would be if you define those functions before the try/except, the conversion and if/elif in an else after the except and the except change to a except ValueError. Also you should use parameters for your functions and the F and C you used are undeclared variables.

```
def celtofah(temp1):
    temp2 = (9/5)*temp1+32
    print temp1," C = ",temp2," F"
def fahtocel(temp1):
    temp2 = (5/9)*(temp1-32)
    print temp1," F = ",temp2," C"

try:
    temperature=raw_input ("Enter temperature in numerals only")
    temp1=float(temperature)
except ValueError:
    print "Please enter a numeric value"
else:
    conversion=raw_input ("Convert to (F)ahrenheit or (C)elsius?")
    if conversion == 'F':
        celtofah(temp1)
    elif conversion == 'C':
        fahtocel(temp1)
```

There are still some other things that you could improve about your code, and perhaps things that I missed, but this can serve as template.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the try/except indentation and if comparison (C and F should be strings):

```
try:
    temperature = raw_input("Enter temperature in numerals only")
    temp1 = float(temperature)
    conversion = raw_input("Convert to (F)ahrenheit or (C)elsius?")


    def celtofah():
        temp2 = (9 / 5) * temp1 + 32
        print temp1, " C = ", temp2, " F"


    def fahtocel():
        temp2 = (5 / 9) * (temp1 - 32)
        print temp1, " F = ", temp2, " C"


    if conversion == "F":
        celtofah()
    elif conversion == "C":
        fahtocel()

except:
    print "Please enter a numeric value"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked. But isn't it usually a practice to exclude the functions from the try block and keep just the input/output statements in it? Doesn't the functions come in the try block in the solution that you have provided?

Comment: Yes, it does create them as scoped functions in the try block. If you do not want to do it that way, just put all functions above the try block, with the `def ...():` line indented to the very left (as you originally had).

Comment: Yes, you are right, the try/except should wrap only the input statement. The solution I've posted is only a quick fix, the best way to do it is like @MatthiasSchreiber posted